# Setup monitoring for API load testing

Tags: api, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-5.0, web-api-testing

I'm new to API Load Testing. Before we started to do API load testing, we need to configure some monitoring setup to monitor CPU usage and JVM heap memory as the test is executed. FYI I'm using Apache JMeter tool to execute the load tests.

For own exercise, I'm trying to do load test using this one sample REST web service: https://reqres.in/

How can I setup monitoring for the server of the sample web service when the web service is not hosted in my own PC? I've tried the JMeter plugin (Perfmon) but I guess this only works when the server is hosted at our own PC. Appreciate for your kind suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your environment set up & access:

1. If you have rdp or ssh access to server(application under test) , you can use visualVm , Jconsole to monitor CPU & Heap memory.
2. In case, you don't have access to remote server - then please work with IT or concerned team to help you configure these tools by opening remote JMX port for performance monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

`but I guess this only works when the server is hosted at our own PC` - that's not true, you can monitor whatever host where the [PerfMon Server Agent](http://jmeterplugins.com/wiki/PerfMonAgent/index.html) is running.

Of course you will need access to the host in order to launch the PerfMon Server Agent so you cannot deploy it onto a random machine in the Internet.

Alternative option is using [SSHMon Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-monitor-server-resource-utilization-with-jmeters-sshmon-listener), in this case you don't need to install anything but you need to have [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell_Protocol) connectivity to the machine(s) you want to monitor.

Comment: So how to extract monitoring from the sample web services https://reqres.in/ ? Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I mean is it possible for us to extract server monitoring from random sample API web services available in the internet?

Comment: it is only possible if you contact site owners and ask for this data

Comment: it also possible to use SSHMon Listener to Linux server?